# iRedmail server deferring mail sent from another internal server

Tags: postfix, iredmail

**Synopsis:**

4 separate servers:

one iRedMail server (new-domain.com)

one application (existing.com)

one node emailer (relay)

one node instance acting as an email password manager for iRedMail server

**Situation:**

All mail sent to and from new-domain.com via Thunderbird, Outlook or Roundcube works great.

mail sent from email password manager to new-domain.com (accounts that live there) through relay gets deferred and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried changing settings in main.cf, master.cf on the relayer

log entry from relay server:

tail -f /var/log/mail.log:

```
Dec 11 16:08:39 email postfix/smtp[24014]: 46430204C: to=<ric@new-domain.com>, relay=none, delay=30, delays=0.08/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to new-domain.com[12.34.56.78]:25: Connection timed out
```

I have tried commenting

```
-o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

in /etc/postfix/master.cf on new-domain.com - to no avail

output of postconf -n on relayer server:

```
user@email:~ $ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 30428800
mydestination = email.new-domain.com, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
myhostname = email.dew-domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated         defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =     btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

output of postconf -M on relayer:

```
    user@email:~# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

what should I try next?

All comments are highly appreciated.

**UPDATE** new log entry:

```
Dec 13 11:02:14 email postfix/error[31144]: warning: connect to private/defer: Connection refused
Dec 13 11:02:14 email postfix/error[31144]: warning: 050D72023: defer service failure
Dec 13 11:02:14 email postfix/error[31144]: 050D72023: to=<richard@new-domain.com>, relay=none, delay=256161, delays=256161/0.04/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to new-domain.com[12.34.56.78]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Comment: from mail.log on the iRedMail server: What does this mean?  
Dec 14 09:20:57 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[48428]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.0.20] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 commands=5/6   
-- I have added that specific ip to mynetworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**
Turns out all I needed to do was send the mail from a known user on the iRedMail server and authenticate him on the emailer in nodemailer.
for an example here is my code in nodemailer:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    pool:true,
    host: 'mail.new-domain.com',
    port: 587,
    secureConnection: true,
    auth : {
        user : 'postmaster@new-domain.com',
        pass : 'password'
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
});
```